# Reverse a sentence using stack in js

Tags: javascript, data-structures, stack, reverse

I have wanted to reverse a sentence using Stack in JavaScript, so here if I give input, Hey, how are you doing? and want to get output done? You are hey, so I traverse the loop and check until space is found, then push that word, then pop all the words from the stack, but it's not showing the undefined, so how can you please rectify that code?

```
function reverseSentence(S){
    let stack = [];
    let word="";
    for(let i=0;i<S.length;i++){
        while(S[i]!=' '&&i<S.length){ 
            word+=S[i]
            i++
        }
       return stack.push(word)
    }
    while(!stack.length){
       return stack.pop()
    }
}
console.log(reverseSentence("Hey, how are you doing?"))
```

Comment: `reverseSentence` doesn't return anything! also `while(!stack.length)`??? so, only if stack is empty?? you should use `.unshift` and then you'll be able to use `.join` ... you'll also want `let word="";` inside the for loop

Comment: even after given return its giving 1 , so can you pls correct and sent that programme?

Comment: `return stack.push(word)` exits the function immediately, returning the length of the array - which of course will be 1 after the first push - not sure why you just added random returns in the wrong place!

Comment: your function can be written as one line - `return S.split(" ").reverse().join(" ");`

Comment: i understood the flow thanks
function reverseSentence(S){
    return S.split(" ").reverse().join(" ");
}
console.log(reverseSentence("Hey, how are you doing?"))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve what you are after is possibly

```js
function reverseSentence(S){
    return S.split(" ").reverse().join(" ");
}
console.log(reverseSentence("Hey, how are you doing?"));
```

However, since you use the word "stack", the following shows how to use array's push/pop to achieve the same goal

```js
function reverseSentence(S){
    const stack = [];
    for(let i=0;i<S.length;i++){
        let word="";
        while(S[i]!=' '&&i<S.length){ 
            word+=S[i]
            i++
        }
       stack.push(word)
    }
    let reverse = stack.pop();
    while(stack.length){
       reverse += " " + stack.pop();
    }
    return reverse;
}
console.log(reverseSentence("Hey, how are you doing?"))
```